# fetching the class which is active in jquery and calling another javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this screenshot

https://prnt.sc/265hkiq
and wanted to fetch the active class so i can call another JS function called as `filter_JS`

basically the `filter_JS` function runs when i click anywhere in pagination, but i am trying to find a way that when a page is reloaded, how can i make sure that it does not reset to 1 back again. because on pageload the function `filter_JS` does not run, it only runs when i click on the pagination

i am trying to do something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if('#pagination').find('span').hasclass('active')
</script>
```

but i think it will fail because on page reload there will no span active and it has already moved to 1, how can i fix it using anything which is not server specific , maybe using using some local storage or how?

any clues, any sample which can guide me with this will be helpful

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "fetch the active class"? Do you mean the element with the active class? Just use `$("#pagination span.active")` to select that element.

Comment: Please post the HTML as text, not a screenshot. You can use `Copy as HTML` in DevTools.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be reminded it is best to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example What event do you want this callback to be executed for? What have you tried? What errors have you encountered?

Comment: ok so my code is like this

Comment: here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d8bmuv0j/ , now if i click any pagination number, i see the class is active changed from regular, how can i fix this thing to always end up which was selected previously when i reloaded the page